# Subversion on RHEL/CentOS 4

Tags: svn, rpm, redhat

Does anyone know of recent subversion RPMs for RHEL 4 ? While RHEL 4 is old - we still have some servers we'd like to upgrade to the latest subversion release - but prepackaged RPMS seems hard to come by, and the newest source is non-trivial to get compiling on such old RHL versions.

Anyone know of recent subversion rpms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CollabNet [offers](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/redhat.html) the latest version with RHEL 4 support.  They don't charge, but registration is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here, which I believe is from RPMForge:

http://packages.sw.be/subversion/

Comment: They seem to only provide RHEL5 rpms for recent subversion releases, not RHEL4

Comment: What version are you looking for? You can likely take the source RPM for the RHEL5 version and roll your own for RHEL4.

Comment: easier said than done. The src rpms for RHEL 5 depends on newer version of *LOTS* of stuff vs RHEL 4 for compiling. thus i was looking for  ready baked rpms from someone that has been through that tarpit.